# Linq to Postgresql

Tags: c#, linq, postgresql, datagridview, mapper

I have a program written in C#, which uses Linq to NHibernate to access the data.  The database backend is Postgres.

In my application, I have a table called `contractors`, which has 10,000 records. Displaying all of the records in this table into a DataGridView sometimes take several minutes.

Are there any ways that I can speed up displaying this data?  What are the major problems that could possibly cause such a slowdown?

Comment: Best speed up: only show the _relevant_ records.

Comment: I bet you have absolutely no valid reason for needing to display 10,000 records on the screen at once. Implement paging, searching, filtering, etc to your grid.

Comment: My brain cannot parse the English in this question.

Comment: Even *if* you fetch 10.000 rows, it should be a matter of seconds at most. Not minutes. Or do you have large columns in your table? Maybe images in bytea columns? Only show  *relevant columns* of *relevant records* then. We will never know unless you tell us more.

Comment: Client-side sorting can be a performance killer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter is right, minutes is excessive. Sorting and/or AutoColumnSize could be tackling you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use server side paging with datagridview.
Datagridview is slow, and you will not display 10k rows to a user.

Comment: It's `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`