# LINQ - .tolist()

Tags: linq

I have a LINQ query. This query retrieves 10000 records from the database. However, the execution of this query takes a long time - about 2 minutes. What could be the reason? The data is then displayed in a DataGridView in a list

Comment: I would suggest not executing "ToList()", instead can you use the results in IEnumberable or IQueryable form?

Comment: There is not enough information. Do you have a fast connection to your database? Do you have proper joins, indexing, etc? Are you including a bunch of navigation properties? Materializing a lot of data and setting up state tracking is not an inexpensive operation. Saying "my code is slow" without any real explanation (or code!) is not particularly useful.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the `ToList()` that is slow and not the adding to the DataGridView?

Answer (score 1):

1. Fire up SQL Server Profiler (found on the tools menu in sql management studio).
2. Study the actual SQL Queries generated and verify that your query really gives *one* query and not 10.000. Sometimes linq-to-sql fails to make a good translation to SQL.
3. Copy the query executed.
4. Paste the query into a sql management studio Window.
5. Enable "Actual query plan"
6. Run the query and check the query plan and see if it suggests any new indexes. Create them and retry.

Comment: It's about Postgres, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184050/linq-to-postgresql